# Removing observers from a WKInterfaceController

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos

Is it recommended to remove observers from instances of WKInterfaceController? If so, is there a recommended lifecycle function in which to do it?

According to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1413994-removeobserver) iOS 9.0 and macOS 11.0 and later don't require removing observers but watchOS isn't mentioned.